# java.lang.NullPointerException at org.apache.jsp.mouseproduct_jsp._jspService(mouseproduct_jsp.java:145)

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, tomcat8, intellij-14

I am getting the following exception while running my application on tomcat8 using IntelliJ Idea14.

```
   25-Apr-2015 16:30:49.221 SEVERE [http-nio-8443-exec-133]    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [] threw exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page /mouseproduct.jsp at line 35
  <%
            String ppic = oc.getPpicture();
           ppic = UT.findProductPicture(ppic, oc.getPcolor());
           int [] wh = SwUtil.getPicWHByMin(application.getRealPath("images").replaceFirst("newportal_admin","newportal")+"\\"+ppic);
              %>
           <img src="<%="../images/"+ppic%>" width="<%=wh[0]%>" height="<%=wh[1]%>" border="0">
 </td>


Stacktrace:] with root cause
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jsp.mouseproduct_jsp._jspService(mouseproduct_jsp.java:145)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:431)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:299)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:614)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1517)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1474)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Which line is `mouseproduct_jsp.java:145`?

Comment: this is at line 145: ppic = UT.findProductPicture(ppic, oc.getPcolor());

Comment: what I didn't understand is the same application runs fine on Tomcat7. But not on Tomcat8

Answer (score 0):

- There is a `NullPointerException` on line no 145 of your code .
- I think that `application.getRealPath("images")` is null .
- To be precise what you can do is find the converted servlet code for this JSP  see the exact line number .
- From the code above there are more than **one** places that can through a NPE .

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by adding jsp-2.3.1 jar, servlet3.1 jar. Since Tomcat 8 implements servlet3.1, jsp2.3 , I needed to upgrade my old jar files.